# Operations using pointers to STL map

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I need to know the difference between two pointer to STL map

Eg.: Using vector is simple

```
vector<pair<int, int> > v;
v.push_back(make_pair(0, 1));
v.push_back(make_pair(2, 3));
v.push_back(make_pair(4, 5));
v.push_back(make_pair(6, 7));
v.push_back(make_pair(8, 9));

vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator itrBegin = v.begin();
vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator itrEnd = v.end();

cout << itrEnd - itrBegin << endl;
```

Output `5`

However, I want to perform the same operation using STL map

```
map<int, int> m;
m[0] = 1;
m[2] = 3;
m[4] = 5;
m[6] = 7;
m[8] = 9;

map<int, int>::iterator itrB = m.begin();
map<int, int>::iterator itrE = m.end();

cout << ????????????? << endl;
```

Comment: That inherently doesn't make sense to do. It makes sense for vectors because the elements are ordered. The map elements are not in any defined order.

Comment: Got it, I think is not possible.

Comment: I have a algorimo using vector that performs this operation. Modified the structure to STL map, I thought it would not influence.

Comment: @Adam map elements are definitely in a specific order...

Comment: The first element in the map is the key and it is sorted based on that key.

Comment: Looks like I was thinking of unordered_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative containers(List, set, multiset, map, multimap) iterators are **Bidirectional iterator** while for sequence container(vector, deque), their iterators are **Random-access iterator**.

**Bidirectional iterator**, only below operators are defined.

```
Expression    Effect
--iter        Steps backward (returns new position)
iter--        Steps backward (returns old position)
```

Which means you can **NOT** call `m.end() - m.begin()` on **Bidirectional iterator**.

**Random-access iterator** have defined below operators.

```
Expression      Effect
iter[n]         Provides access to the element that has index n
iter+=n         Steps n elements forward (or backward, if n is negative)
iter-=n         Steps n elements backward (or forward, if n is negative)
iter+n          Returns the iterator of the nth next element
n+iter          Returns the iterator of the nth next element
iter-n          Returns the iterator of the nth previous element
iter1-iter2     Returns the distance between iter1 and iter2
iter1<iter2     Returns whether iter1 is before iter2
iter1>iter2     Returns whether iter1 is after iter2
iter1<=iter2    Returns whether iter1 is not after iter2
iter1>=iter2    Returns whether iter1 is not before iter2
```

So use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), it works as long as iterator is [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
std::cout << std::distance(iterB, iterE) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Interesting, I like your answer, I will test